# Solving a linear recurrence equation: $S_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_{n-i}S_i$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, closed-form

I am wondering whether it is possible to express the following recurrence relation in terms of the serie $a$ and $S_{0}$.

> $$
> S[0] = S_{0}
> $$
>   $$
> \forall n > 0 \text{   }S[n] = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} a[n-i]S[i]  
> $$

I computed the first values of $S$ and tried to find its expression and prove it by induction but I failed. I also tried the $z$-transform without any success.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. By considering $\sum_{n=0}^\infty S_nx^n,\, \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$, one may use the *formal* [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) of two series:
$$
\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty S_nx^n\right)\cdot \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{i=0}^n a_{n-i}S_i\right)x^n\tag1
$$ which gives here
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty S_nx^n\right)\cdot \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n\right)&=a_0S_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_{n-i}S_i+a_0S_n\right)x^n
\\\\&=a_0S_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(S_n+a_0S_n\right)x^n
\\\\&=-S_0+(1+a_0)\sum_{n=0}^\infty S_nx^n
\end{align}
$$ thus *formally*

> $$
> \sum_{n=0}^\infty S_nx^n=\frac{S_0}{1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n} \tag2
> $$

We are then looking for a power series of a reciprocal-like power series, there is no simple closed form, one may take a look at [Ira Gessel's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53384/power-series-of-the-reciprocal-does-a-recursive-formula-exist-for-the-coeffic/53407#53407).

Comment: If we write the denominator of $(2)$ as $1-A(x)$ then formally one has $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty S_n x^n=S_0\left(1+A+A^2+\cdots\right),$$ a cute if not exactly practical expansion.

Comment: @Semiclassical Yes, this is what Ira Gessel pointed out then giving closed form with multinomial coefficients.

Comment: If we use ( 'naively' ) a 'generating function method' we get that $\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}S_{i}x^{i} = \sum_{r}A_{r}\delta\left(x - r\right)$ where $\left\lbrace r\right\rbrace$ are the roots of $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n} = 0$ with arbitrary constants $\left\lbrace A_{r}\right\rbrace$.

Comment: @FelixMarin Good catch!